# how to parse this in android with json

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

I want to parse this json in android. Can you help me how to parse, if i need to start from head to parse or from results for this I don't know. Can you help me

```
{ 
"head": 
   { 
    "link": [], 
    "vars": ["city", "country"] 
    }, 
"results": 
    { 
        "distinct": false, 
        "ordered": true, 
        "bindings": 
            [ 
                { 
                    "city": 
                        { 
                            "type": "uri",
                             "value": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Ferizaj"
                        } ,
                    "country": 
                        { 
                        "type": "uri", 
                        "value": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Kosovo" 
                        }
                 } 
            ] 
    } 
 }
```

Comment: can you help me how to parse this

Comment: What values do you want?

Comment: values what I want is just "value" in city and country

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, first of all the JSON string you've given is invalid. I've written my answer based on the correct version of the JSON string that you have provided

```
 { 
"head": 
   { 
    "link": [], 
    "vars": ["city", "country"] 
    }, 
"results": 
    { 
        "distinct": false, 
        "ordered": true, 
        "bindings": 
            [ 
                { 
                    "city": 
                        { 
                            "type": "uri",
                             "value": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Ferizaj"
                        } ,
                    "country": 
                        { 
                        "type": "uri", 
                        "value": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Kosovo" 
                        }
                 } 
            ] 
    } 
 }
```

Now, to get the "values", you'll need to do this.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
JSONObject results = jsonObject.getJSONObject("results");
JSONArray bindings = results.getJSONArray("bindings");
for (int i = 0; i < bindings.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject binding = bindings.getJSONObject(i);
    JSONObject city = binding.getJSONObject("city");
    // Get value in city
    String cityValue = city.getString("value");
    Log.d("CITY", cityValue);
    JSONObject country = binding.getJSONObject("country");
    // Get value in country
    String countryValue = country.getString("value");
    Log.d("COUNTRY", countryValue);
}
```

Comment: This json is from this link: http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20DISTINCT?city%20?country%20WHERE%20%7B%20?city%20rdf:type%20dbpedia-owl:City%20;%20rdfs:label%20?label%20;%20dbpedia-owl:country%20?country%20FILTER%20%28regex%28?country,%20%22Albania%22%29%29%20%7D&format=application/json&timeout=100000&debug=on
I try to create application with sparql query from dbpedia

Comment: I copy paste that link and it says "Virtuoso 22023 Error The request does not contain text of SPARQL query"

Comment: i put the link in question, you see and get copy and now don't have error

Comment: I need value in X and population, abstract,lat,long and flag to parse with android

Comment: Ok, I will help you. But please post it as another question because the problem doesn't belong to this question or else this question will get deleted too.

Comment: i post the question, here is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30846231/how-ta-parse-this-json-in-android